# What are the keywords of fantasy that might deliver the feeling of fantasy

Tags: fantasy, word-choice

I am asking about the keywords that could make anyone feel fantasy.

it will be better if every one who will see this post could tell me what their feelings are or express their feelings in one keyword that delivers fantasy.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Arcane. The word implies being out of the ordinary, without implying good, bad, or any kind of subsequent action.

Comment: Welcome to Writers! I'm sorry to say that I'm casting the final vote to place this on hold. Please have a look at our [tour] and [help pages](http://writers.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance about how to edit this into a question that'll work on this site. It's unfortunate that your first question here is getting closed, and I hope you don't look at this as a rejection but as an opportunity for improvement.

Answer (score 5):

### Lexical (Semantic) Fields

I'm not going to give you words to describe fantasy - that's not the point of this site. Instead, I'm going to introduce you to what a *lexical field* is. A lexical field is a 'family' of related words. This is also known as a *semantic field*.

For example, here are some words in the lexical field of nature:

- Tree
- Forest
- Green
- Sylvan

By coming up with words relating to one lexical field and using that in your writing, you can reinforce a certain mood. For example, you can restrict yourself to using lovely words, or sad words, and that will help reinforce the mood of your novel.

What I suggest you do, is think of some words you associate with fantasy. Create a lexical field of fantasy words to use in your writing. You're looking to make the setting as accurate as possible to what is in your mind. If it's sad fantasy, use sad words, etc.

Due to this, I don't believe it's right to just hand out words to you. It depends on many factors, and you should decide for yourself. Use a semantic field to assist you in creating a true sense of setting within your writing.

I hope this helped you.

Comment: Why did you remove "more" before "better" in the original post? It was so cute...

Comment: @Lew I didn't notice "more better" in the original post, but I can understand why it was edited: Where I live, the expression is mo' betta.

Comment: @RobtA we might be neighbors :)

Comment: Yeah I did... @Lew.

Comment: Great answer! I would also specify: create a lexical field for *your* fantasy, so that it is different from any generic fantasy world. Create your world starting from the language, the lexicon.

Answer (score 1):

**Choose words and symbols to illustrate *your* fantasy, rather than something generic.**

First off, there are a number of free online tools for exploring words' synonyms, connotations, and impact. One I like is: http://graphwords.com

Secondly, if you figure out what makes your fantasy unique, and find words that illustrate and support that, you'll be telling your own story, rather than some generic (and IMHO thus more boring) story.

So if your fantasy involves, say, magical trees, find/search for words related to trees, folktales about trees, tree spirits (dryads), origins of Christmas trees, etc. Use the resulting info to 'color' the world your story takes place in and its characters.  If dragons are a focus, make word/concept lists to support flying, fire, jewels, caverns, treasure etc.

And you can do this with names (though best to avoid being obvious about it.)  For example, 'Thorin Oakenshield' gives some character hints that 'Thorin Jones' just doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Words individually do not give the feeling of any genre. It is how you put them together to create a picture in the reader's mind. Just as a painter may use the same pallet of colors to paint a unicorn or a cart horse, so an author can use the same pallet of words to paint a fairy palace in the air of a gritty tenement in New York.

Read the opening of some of the great fantasies like Wind in the Willows or LOTR and you will find that they use very ordinary words. It is how those words are combined to produce images that makes the difference.